# Detection of event "property changed"

Tags: qt, qml

There is a property `var1` declared in file1.qml. The property is visible in other qml files, but it is not possible to detect its event `onChange`.

file1.qml:

```
Item {
 id: obj1Id
 property int var1: 0
 ...
 Component.onCompleted: {
  var1=2
  var1Changed()             <<<<<<<<<<<< emit signal "changed"
 }
 onVar1Changed: {}          <<<<<<<<<<<< signal is detected
 ...
}
```

file2.qml:

```
Item {
 id: obj2Id
 property int local_var: 0
 ...
 Component.onCompleted: {
  local_var = obj1Id.var1       <<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<< It is OK
 }
 onVar1Changed: {}              <<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<< Error
 obj1Id.onVar1Changed: {}       <<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<< Error
 ...
}
```

Is it possible this approach or in file2.qml have to add `property int local_var: obj1Id.var1` and then `onLocal_varChanged: {}`?

Comment: please provide a real [mre], and not pseudo-code

Comment: And don't just say "Error". Give the actual error message.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are few moments in your code that could bring misunderstanding. Makes sense to figure out it first.

You wrote:

```
 Component.onCompleted: {
  var1=2
  var1Changed()             <<<<<<<<<<<< emit signal "changed"
 }
```

but you do not need to manually emit that signal. QML will do it for you. So, actually nothing will change without that line.

---

You wrote

```
 property int local_var: 0
 ...
 Component.onCompleted: {
  local_var = obj1Id.var1       <<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<< It is OK
 }
```

this is totally valid code, but you need to understand that this is one-time assign and not a binding of a value `obj1Id.var1` to `local_var`, e.g. if you change `obj1Id.var1` -- do not expect `local_var` to be changed respectively.

To make a real binding of a value you may use [`Binding` component](https://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qml-qtqml-binding.html) or [`Qt.binding` for creating property bindings from JavaScript](https://doc.qt.io/Qt-5/qtqml-syntax-propertybinding.html#creating-property-bindings-from-javascript) or as you've proposed -- add property `int local_var: obj1Id.var1`.

---

In any case you need to have a valid reference to your `obj1Id` in your `file2.qml`.

If bindings approach doesn't fit you -- you can use [`Connections` QML Type](https://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qml-qtqml-connections.html).

In your case this code should be placed inside `file2.qml`:

```
Connections {
  target: obj1Id
  onVar1Changed: console.log("obj1Id.var1 changed")
}
```

Comment: Thank you very much for your answer and links! Regards, Peter